# info.php uses 7.2 but 5.6 is enabled

Tags: php, apache2

localhost/info.php shows php 7.2 being used but it's disabled and I'm trying to use 5.6.

This does not help:

```
sudo a2dismod php7.2
sudo a2enmod php5.6
sudo service apache2 restart
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php5.6
```

After this `php -v` uses 5.6.

This causes mcrypt extension not being found even though it is enabled and installed in 5.6.

Comment: why would you want to downgrade?

Comment: for older magento 1 version which uses php5.6

Comment: Update Magento instead.

Comment: this is not my choice to update it. Problem is with php version not changing not framework itself.

Comment: @Trenox it is a problem, support was stopped ages ago - magento1 is now 100% vulnerable

Comment: Doesn't Apache select which PHP version to use? Perhaps there's something you can put in a `.htaccess`?

Comment: @treyBake I know this, theres more than just upgrading magento version. If this was for me I would do it, now its not my choice. Setup is this magento 1 and php 5.6. Why would apache2 still use 7.2 not 5.6?

Comment: @Trenox Does this work? https://serverfault.com/questions/428800/how-do-i-tell-apache-which-php-to-use/469849